# CakePHP security component With WYSIHTML5

Tags: security, cakephp

When using the wysiHTML5 textarea replacement, cakePHP's security component is raising a security error.

I have tried to prevent this by unlocking that field

```
$this->Security->unlockedFields = array('detail', 'ItemDetail', 'data[Item][detail]');
```

But the post is still blackholed.  Is there a way to retain formtampering protection for the other fields when using JS replacement for one field in the form like this?

Comment: Are you *creating* the text area using the standard FormHelper and *then* applying the JavaScript? Or did you add the textarea 'by hand'? Have you compared the posted data with / without using wysiHTML5? What is the difference? Are fields added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue. Apparently WYSIHTML5 is adding a field to the posted data called '_wysihtml5_mode'.

I didn't want to tamper with the WYSIHTML5 javascript itself, so I added the following code my controller, so the Security helper won't trigger a blackhole:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    if (isset($this->request->data['_wysihtml5_mode'])) unset($this->request->data['_wysihtml5_mode']);
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

Comment: nice.  i also worked out i was passing fields to unlocked incorrectly, it should be: "Item.Relation.Id" for eg select boxes being dynamically updated